# String overrides doesn't override certain Commerce components

Tags: 7, theming, commerce, string-overrides

It actually overrides everything except 'Order total', I do not understand how that component doesn't get overwritten by String overrides.  Order total is in Checkout page.

```
<table class="commerce-price-formatted-components">
<tbody>
<tr class="component-type-commerce-price-formatted-amount odd">
<td class="component-title">Order total</td>
<td class="component-total">$5,100.00</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I cleared my caches.

Answer (score 0):

It's a field label, meaning it doesn't get passed through the basic string translation system. You'd need to use something like the i18n Field module instead.

Comment: It did change many other labels.